# LocalDB (mdf) compaction

Tags: c#, sql-server, localdb

I am considering to use LocalDB in future projects, instead of OleDB (MDB).

Do I need to *compact* database from time to time? And if yes, then how?

I found what there is a `Shrink` option in case of SQL database (MDF, right?), possibility to define autoshrink and repair somehow. Perhaps I don't need to do a compaction (which in my understanding is creating new database and copying actual content into it, so all *outdated* content is removed), but it is enough to enable shrinking somehow (which is an option, so that server periodically do a kind of *garbage collection*, by moving *garbage* to the end of database file and truncating the file).

It is also interesting, how well shrink works in regards of file system fragmentation (my guess is not very good).

All-in-all I'd prefer to have compaction, the idea (code) of how to perform it and how to determine when it's needed (criteria to perform compaction).

I see, there is BACKUP command, perhaps compacting will looks like: 1) backup 2) recreate database 3) restore from backup?

Comment: Can you give more context on why you think you might need to compact? The only reason I can think of is if you were worried about hitting the database size limit, which I believe is 10GB now for LocalDB.

Comment: MDF limit is 16 TB, MDB - 2 Gb (not enough tbh). I was learning (~15 years ago) what database do not *physically* delete records, but mark them as such. Maybe there are also other operations, what are not performed as they are thought to be (indexing, updates, etc). So if you do lots of changes - you database will grow up, becoming slower and may even become buggy. In case of MDB, compacting is a must, and I know how to do it with the use of JRO. But I didn't find anything like this related to MDF (or shall I say LocalDB, or perhaps SQL express?).

Comment: I put my attempt at answering the question below, and added sql-server tag to draw the real experts to this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LocalDB is SQL Server Express, which is SQL Server. General SQL Server guidelines will usually apply to LocalDB as well, unless you have very specific situation. Note that SQL Server Express (including LocalDB) has an additional limit on the MDF file size, which in 10GB in SQL Server Express 2012.

One thing to keep in mind is that the format was designed to be fast, and not compact. For example, an empty database will create an MDF file that is a couple MBs big.

`autogrow` and `autoshrink` seem to be the way to go for managing the MDF size, if you want to keep it down as much as possible. There are performance-related trade-offs, discussed in [this KB 315512 article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315512/en-us) and [this post by Paul Randall, including the discussion in comments](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/why-you-should-not-shrink-your-data-files/).

As per file system fragmentation - creating the database with big enough file size should help, as the OS should be able to find big continuous block(s) of disk space easier when asked at once. When the database file grows and shrinks it is more likely to be fragmented at the file system level. I found [this post](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3008/solving-sql-server-database-physical-file-fragmentation/) as well, discussing using a tool to "manually" defragment a given file. Looks promising, but I have not tested it.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. It become more clear now. Can you confirm, what I don't have to do anything to have *autoshrink* enabled (using localdb, creating database programmatically with `DataContext` dbml)? I can live with that 25% extra, was afraid of something like 2000% =D

Comment: I don't have LocalDB installation handy to test it, but a simple test should suffice. Just create a database and see the value of `autoshrink` option. This should work: `select DATABASEPROPERTYEX('<my db>', 'IsAutoShrink'). Details: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186823.aspx . Obviously the default value could change in the future, so you might just set it yourself just to be sure in some setup step, depending on your application.